# Wrong condition evaluation using gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, redhat, c++20

I have a code that depends on many external libraries that works fine in **debug** mode but it crashes in **release** mode.
When checking the root cause I found that there is a true condition that's evaluated to false

My code looks like

```
#include <iostream>

enum fruits
{
a, b, c
}
...
int main()
{
   auto condition (fruits::a == 99);
   std::cout << condition;
   if (fruits::a == 99) std::cout << " FATAL ERROR ";
   ...
}
```

The progam outputs :

```
0 FATAL ERROR
```

The program is using c++20 with O2 optimisation flag

The issue is not present if I execute the code in a separated program.

Comment: The problem is not in the shown code. You most likely have undefined behavior somewhere else in your program.

Comment: You should start with valgrind, all sanitizers available from gcc and maybe also use some memory debug libraries. I am sure that you have some  UB, race conditions or especially out of bounds access. As we can't help you on the given code, I vote to close.

Comment: @user17732522 the issue is always here and it's systemically crashes at the same line with the same values so I don't think that it's an undefined behavior.

Comment: @SaadRami No, that is exactly how undefined behavior somewhere else in the program often manifests. The compiler probably made some optimization based on some undefined behavior in the rest of your program that effectively eliminated the `if` branch. That is then also why it manifests only in release mode where the compiler optimizes more aggressively.

Comment: @Klaus,  find it, I used the optimization option -O2
This flag is the root cause of this issue. In the gcc documentation I didn't find anything about this

Comment: @SaadRami Start by adding `-Wall -Wextra -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=address` and go through all compile-time warnings and sanitizer messages that generates. See also https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html for more sanitizer options.

Comment: If -O2 results in wrong execution, your program is broken. Your idea of a "root cause" is totally wrong! You have definitely some UB, race condition or wrong memory access in your program! YOU have to find it. At some point of development it will also break with O0 or even if it not crashes it will result in wrong behavior. I am not the only person who tells you that your code is broken. So please start to investigate YOUR bug!

Comment: @user17732522 thank you for your help I will test using the given options

Comment: [MCVE] or it didn't happen. `on many external libraries` What libraries? `in debug mode but it crashes in release mode.` what flags are you using in every "mode"? What can you tell us about your program and environment? `looks like` Can you post _the exact_ code that you use? There is little point in posting "looks like" code, it's not the code that you use, it's unrelated. Have you debugged the program at the point that the wrong "condition" is taken? What is the assembly of the function that has the condition? Are there multiple threads? Which gcc version and redhat version are using? Etc..